Given a partition $\mathcal{F}$ of a set $A$, $R = \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{F}}(X \times X)$ is an equivalence relation on $A$
I'm trying to prove the following statement from Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 220):

Suppose $A$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a partition of $A$. Let $R = \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{F}}(X \times X)$. Then $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.

The reflexivity of $R$ is proved by Velleman himself in the book, and there is another answer on this forum concerning its transitivity. To prove symmetry, I've tried the following:
Suppose $x \in A$ and $y \in A$. Also suppose $(x, y) \in R = \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{F}}(X \times X)$, i.e. there is some $X \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $x \in X$ and $y \in X$ (in fact, such $X$ is unique since $\mathcal{F}$ is a partition). Then, since $x$ and $y$ belong to the same $X$, $(y, x) \in R = \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{F}}(X \times X)$ as well. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, we conclude that $R$ is symmetric. $\square$
Does my proof suffice to actually prove symmetry? I feel suspicious because I haven't used the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a partition, and I've simply assumed that $x$ and $y$ belong to the same $X \in \mathcal{F}$. Can someone clarify?

Your proof is fine. The fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a partition is needed for transitivity, but not for symmetry.

Oh, okay. Thanks. For some reason I thought it was too simple to be correct.

I presume you mean that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.

Sorry, it's a typo of course. I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing that out.
